# Using GitLab API to set external issues tracker settings?

Tags: jira, gitlab

I'm using GitLab with an external issue tracker (JIRA), and it works well.

My problem is when I create a new GitLab project (using API), I have to go the GitLab's project settings and **manually** select the issue tracker I want to use and **manually** enter the project's id of my external issue tracker.

This screen will be more eloquent: 
[image: GitLab external issue tracker settings]
<sub>(source: [bayimg.com](http://image.bayimg.com/9f43dcebf9a03c03e711b0e208d9e46ca95d6781.jpg))</sub>

(The two fields I am talking about are "*Issue tracker*" and "*Project name or id in issues tracker*")

So here is my question: is there any way to set up this two fields **automatically**, using API or other ? Currently, [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html) does not mention anything about external issues tracker settings.

Comment: It is not possible to set the external issues-tracker settings automatically with GitLab API, but I achieved this using [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code helped me to automatically set the GitLab's external issues-tracker settings, using [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/) and [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). 
This code is absolutely not 100% good, but it shows the main idea, wich is to recreate the corresponding `POST` request that the web form sends.

```
// 1 - Prepare the HttpClient object :
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
LaxRedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new LaxRedirectStrategy();

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .setRedirectStrategy(redirectStrategy)
                .build();

try {
        // 2 - Second you need to get the "CSRF Token", from a <meta> tag in the edit page :
        HttpUriRequest getCsrfToken = RequestBuilder.get()
                        .setUri(new URI("http://localhost/_NAMESPACE_/_PROJECT_NAME_/edit"))
                        .build();
        CloseableHttpResponse responseCsrf = httpclient.execute(getCsrfToken);
        try {
                HttpEntity entity = responseCsrf.getEntity();
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                String csrf_token = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "csrf-token").get(0).attr("content");

                // 3 - Fill and submit the "edit" form with new values :
                HttpUriRequest updateIssueTracker = RequestBuilder
                                .post()
                                .setUri(new URI("http://localhost/_NAMESPACE_/_PROJECT_NAME_"))
                                .addParameter("authenticity_token", csrf_token)
                                .addParameter("private_token", "_MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN_")
                                .addParameter("_method", "patch")
                                .addParameter("commit", "Save changes")
                                .addParameter("utf8", "✓")
                                .addParameter("project[issues_tracker]", "jira")
                                .addParameter("project[issues_tracker_id]", "_MY_JIRA_PROJECT_NAME_")
                                .addParameter("project[name]", "...")
                                ...
                                .build();

                CloseableHttpResponse responseSubmit = httpclient.execute(updateIssueTracker, httpContext);

        } finally {
                responseCsrf.close();
        }
} finally {
        httpclient.close();
}
```

Change `_NAMESPACE_/_PROJECT_NAME_` to make it corresponds to your project URL, change `_MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN_` with your admin account's token, and change `_MY_JIRA_PROJECT_NAME_` with ... your jira project's name.