# Edit Gitlab project setting for wiki_enabled via API

Tags: gitlab

I am in the process of migrating multiple svn repositories to git using the bulk import from Gitlab that automatically creates projects. Those projects have the wiki enabled, so I now want to change the setting for wiki_enabled to false.

The documentation doesn´t mention a PUT command to do this and while trying different things with curl, searching the web and stackoverflow, I couldn´t find a solution.

Is this even possible and if so how?

Comment: I had the same issue with the GitLab `external-issue-tracker`: as for your `wiki_enabled`, I could not set it with the API and I don't wanted to do it mannualy. I used Apache HttpClient to generate the corresponding `POST` request (the one for the GitLab web form, not for the API) and it works. You'll have to change `.addParameter("project[issues_tracker]", "jira")` by something like `.addParameter("project[wiki_enabled]", "false")`. This is a very dirty solution, but it does work.
Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514118/using-gitlab-api-to-set-external-issues-tracker-settings

Comment: Thx, will try that out if there is no other solution (and possibly create an enhancement request in Gitlab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution...

Apparently the API cannot edit existing projects, see http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3904506-full-crud-operations-via-api-for-projects

But it is possible to locally connect to the database (without knowing the password it seems) and then using SQL:

```
gitlab-rails dbconsole
update projects set wiki_enabled = false;
```